# Discord.py: async on_message(message) syntax error?

Tags: discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

Here is a snippet of my code

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    global afkdict
                   
    if str(message.author.id) in afkdict:
       afkdict.pop(str(message.author.id))

    for member in message.mentions:  
        if member != message.author:  
            if member.id in afkdict:  
                afkmsg = afkdict[str(member.id)]  
                   
                await message.channel.send(f"{member} is AFK: {afkmsg}")
                   
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

I got the following error (screenshot)
[image]

To clarify, I do NOT have 2 on_message events in my code either.

additionally, I use python 3.8.x with heroku hosting, so I don’t believe python version is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, my original python version was 3.8.x. After I changed it to 3.10.0, it actually spotted the error for me. It turned out that the syntax error was caused by a pair of parentheses that weren’t closed :C

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Okay, with the updated question, since the complaint isn't actually abount indentation, I'd say the problem is that `python` on your server refers to a version which didn't yet support the `async def` syntax - probably `python2`, as this is the default in many cases. Changing the invocation to `python3 bot.py` is likely to fix this.

*<s>You seem to simply lack the necessary indentation for your function. This is, just like the compiler says, a syntax error, not related in any way to your app's logic. You should add 4 spaces (or a tab, whichever you're using in your code) in the beginning of each line which you want to belong to the `on_message` function.
This is necessay because, unlike most other languages, Python doesn't use special markers (like `{` and `}`) for compound code statements. Instead, it expects the lines of such a block to share the same indentation level, and to have it rise by a fixed step with each layer of nested-ness.</s>*

Comment: Sorry, there was an indentation error in my text, the real code is indented properly

Comment: @j-muzhen, your indentation is still wrong: the function definition (the first two lines, starting with `@` and `def`) should not be indented. Also, it would help if you sent the whole error output, and not just the one line `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, if you claim that indentation is not the problem, because the rest of your code seems perfectly fine in terms of syntax

Comment: sorry, updated the question. I’ll put The whole error output here too

Comment: @JMuzhen, I've changed the answer accordingly - see if it helps now